# How to display dynamic PHP ID in chartjs

Tags: php, jquery, chart.js

I am using chartjs inside PHP foreach for multiple charts. Im in a situation to call dynamic ID. I want to use ID as fulltime_32, fulltime_33 and so on. in the PHP foreach statement. I am getting error when dynamically use the ID.

Please check the code,

```php
PHP code -- $sid = $source_id; 
- Dynamic ID for example 32,33,34,35,36

fulltime_32[context[0].dataIndex]; to fulltime_$sid[context[0].dataIndex];   


    <script>    
        const fulltime_32 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        const data = {
           labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
           datasets: [{
              label: 'Weekly Sales',
              data: [18, 12, 6, 9, 12, 3, 9],              
              borderWidth: 1
           }]
        };
        
        const config = {
           type: 'bar',
           data,
           options: {          
              plugins: {             
                 tooltip: {
                    callbacks: {
                       title: function (context) {
                          console.log(context);    
                          return return fulltime_32[context[0].dataIndex];
                       },
                    }
                 }
              },
           }
        };
        
       
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically set the JS id like so:

```php
<script>
  <?php foreach($data as $value) : ?>
    const fulltime_<?php echo $data->sid; ?> = ...;
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</script>
```

Comment: I am using the same, when callbacks i am getting the error ... 
callbacks:{  
  title: function(context){
    console.log(context);
                                                  
    return fulltime_<?php echo $data->sid; ?>[context[0].dataIndex];
  }
}

Comment: it seems like your php is not compiled.. please open a clean file `index.php` with the contents `<?php phpinfo(INFO_GENERAL);` and see if you get the phpinfo page or just a text.